# Vector Fields given a set of differential equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to draw (by hand) the vector field given a set of differential equations. Consider the following:

> $\frac{dx}{dt} = x+y$
>
> $\frac{dy}{dt} = -x + y$

Normally, when I am given just one differential equation, like $\frac{dy}{dt} = y$, I can easily compute the values by hand and can plot this out - think of this as picking coordinates of $(t,y)$. Would this approach be the same for this given system of differential equations? I'm more interested in the process, but a graph of how this should look like would be greatly appreciated as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $x(t)=a$ and $y(t)=b$ for some time $t$, then the "arrow" emanating from the point $(a,b)$ points in the direction $(a+b,-a+b)$. This is the vector field to be drawn. For example, using Mathematica,

```
StreamPlot[{a + b, -a + b}, {a, -4, 4}, {b, -4, 4}]
```

gives

[image]

Comment: Hi rogerl. I love this answer, but I have a question: where did $x(t) = x$ and $y(t) = y$ come from? How did you select these functions?

Comment: See edit above. Just notational confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Usually you get a good overview by computing the isoclines for the horizontal, vertical and diagonal directions, that is, for

- $\dot y=0$ you find $y=x$,
- $\dot x = 0$ where $y=-x$,
- $\dot y=\dot x$ for $x=0$ and
- $\dot y=-\dot x$ for $y=0$.

Then you need an idea on the orientation of the direction vectors, which is consistent over large area.